# Laravel 7.3 route shows blank page without error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing, laravel-7

This route was working for months but suddenly it went blank and I got no errors and logs for it. I tried cleaning the cache using "php artisan optimize:clear" and cleared all the possible caches, but it doesn't work!
I haven't had any changes related to this route and view. It seems like a bug. My Laravel version is 7.30.4.
And I'm sure it's a route-related issue because changes in view don't affect it.

Comment: Give us some more information. Any changes on the server?

Comment: No enough details. Check your web server logs (In Ubuntu, Apache error log is /var/log/apache2/error.log)

Also you can try giving the relevant write permissions to your storage and cache directories. Maybe the permission has been lifted.

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei No, I undo anything I've done. My server is IIS - Windows server 2019 and there is no info because nothing special happened before this issue.

Comment: @ParaD 
I changed the view file name and the problem is gone. It's so weird so that I can't understand what was the problem. I also checked server log file, the error was: “The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly”
But I don't know if the problem is with the server. This error only belongs to this view file.

Comment: @TopStars My guess is, could be a cache conflict. But you never know. Error message doesn't say much.

Comment: @ParaD Yes I think the same, could be cache. Maybe I need to migrate to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Yo should put some debug or code on the Handler.php, just to be sure if there's an Exception. Also change your .env enviorment to not production, don't forget to run a "php artisan optimize". Hope this info helps you.